# Sync numbers displayed with C3.js gauge

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, c3.js

I am using a slider in R's shiny to control a C3.js gauge. I have changed the duration of transition to a large number to clearly see the transitions. However, the numerical values switch directly to the final value. They don't increment or decrement in sync with the gauge. How is it possible to do this?

[image]

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'C3Gauge',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

    // create an empty chart
    var chart = null;

    return {

      renderValue: function(x) {

        // check if the chart exists
        if(chart === null){

          // the chart did not exist and we want to create a new chart via c3.generate
          chart = c3.generate({
                bindto: el,
                data: {
                    json: x,
                    type: 'gauge',
                },
                gauge: {
                    label:{
                        format: function(value, ratio){ return value;}
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    width: 15,
                    units: ''
                },
                transition: {
                    duration: 5000
                },

            });

          // store the chart on el so we can get it later
          el.chart = chart;
        }

        // at this stage the chart always exists 
        // get the chart stored in el and update it
        el.chart.load({json: x});

      }
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: decrease the transition duration right now it's set at `5000ms`. try  `transition: {
                    duration: 200
                },`

Comment: That won't help. The desired behaviour is to have the gauge slowly transition to its next state (ie a long transition.duration). Simultaneously, I'd like the numbers to change in sync with the changing gauge.